# Custom Mongo ObjectId for inserts

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, elasticsearch, mongodb-.net-driver

**Some Background:**

I'm using MongoDB in tandem with ElasticSearch via the mongo-elasticsearch river.  In Elasticsearch I want the structure of my documents to look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "SomeId-AnotherId",

    ... // all the other lovely denormalized data
}
```

SomeId-AnotherId is something I create when I denormalize my data.  The reason I need that structure is that I need to be able to say `http://elasticsearch/index/type/SomeId-AnotherId` to retrieve a document.

I denormalize my data (a C# app) then I insert into MongoDB (this data then goes into ES via the river as mentioned above).  When I insert into MongoDB I am currently under the impression that I need to set a BsonId on my model which Mongo uses to index the document.  This can be an ObjectId or any other type such as string or int etc as long as I add the [BsonId] attribute.

My model looks like this:

```
public class Model {
    [BsonId]
    public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

And I set it like this:

```
model.Id = string.format("{0}-{1}", someId, anotherId);
```

**The Problem**

At the moment I'm seeing ~1,500 documents getting into Mongo from an insert of ~10,000.  I had a look at the ids I was generating for my model objects and there were definitely a lot over 12 bytes.  Would mongo just refuse those and not write them?

**Bson Id's are 12bytes - so does this mean that if I create my own ID (in the format: "SomeId-AnotherId") it should also only be 12 bytes long?  Anyway around this?**

I don't want to use mongos default objectId for these documents because as I mentioned above, once the doc is in elasticsearch I want to be able to get a document in a particular way (using "SomeId-AnotherId" in a URI).

**Final Notes:**

I'm aware that I can add another ID property to my model called something like ElasticId and then configure Elasticsearch to look for this property and use it as the _id of the elasticsearch document.  If I did this then I could use Mongos default IDs and all would be well.  However, I would sacrifice elasticsearch performance and I would also need to store an extra field in elastic search that I don't want.

Sorry for the massive brain dump btw!!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I've solved this now.  On reflection it was a bit obvious and a massive oversight on my part.

I'm inserting in batches of 10,000 but the total number of records is over 40million.  My ids were guaranteed to be unique on a per batch basis - so there could be duplicates in other batches.

I turned on SafeMode and started to see the exceptions I was getting - they were coming from mongo and they were duplicate key exceptions.  I found that the mongo csharp client drops all remaining data in your batch as soon as it gets a duplicate key error.  So I was seeing the first 1500 of a batch going in, then I was receiving a duplicate key error and then the rest of the batch wasn't being inserted.  Which totally makes sense.

So for now I'm doing single inserts which are actually almost as quick as a batch insert.  When I get a duplicate key error I log it but keep going as I don't care about duplicates in my scenario.

Thanks for the help @Philipp.

Answer (score 9):

The `_id` field of a MongoDB document *can* be a 12-byte UUID, but it doesn't have to. According to [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField), you can use any non-array value as `_id`, as long as you can make sure that it's unique.

Comment: OK - well that rules out truncation which is what I was wondering about.  I've now tried just supplying my own unique id as a string (I renamed my property to _id).  I've chucked it all at mongo and still only ~1,500 out of the 10,000 are inserted.  So this did not solve my problem.  I'm completely stumped!

Comment: Just further to my above comment - If I use the default ID Mongo generates instead of supplying my own, all 10,000 are inserted fine.  I do not want to do that though.  I guess I'm wondering why it makes a difference if you use your own ID instead of a mongo generated one.  Also, the ID is definitely uinque.

Comment: What's the type of your custom ID? Are you sure you aren't converting it to ObjectId somewhere in your application causing a tructation? And can you really rule out that there is a bug in your ID generation code which generates duplicate IDs?

Comment: If I distinct my collection by ID then the count remains the same.  So the ID's are distinct.  If I go to the SQL DB I'm denormalizing from and distinct by the two field I'm creating an ID from then the count is the same.  So from my point of view, the IDs are OK.  The ids are strings.  I haven't decorated the id with any attributes, just named it "_id" so that mongo can pick it up properly.  I'm going to try inserting one of the objects that didn't make it through the mongo terminal now and see why it gets rejected...  cheers for the help btw

Comment: Just an idea, but could there be an unique index on the collection which gets in your way?

Comment: Not sure - as soon as the data gets to mongo my understanding of whats happening goes down to 'novice level'.  I'll have a google now - cheers.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion: if I take the JSON representation of one the items that did not get inserted into Mongo and try and insert it through the mongo terminal, it works... So - if I use the standard object Id - I can insert all 10,000 records with no problems.  If I use my own Unique ID, only 1500 records are inserted - BUT if I insert the dropped records manually via the terminal, they are OK.  Incredible.